# Multitouch - PointerIndex out of range

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouchlistener, pinch, motionevent

I try to fix an issue which appears in my code when I added multitouch functions in my app.
The problem seems to come from ACTION_POINTER_DOWN :

```
private float oldDist = 0;
backCard.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

            switch(me.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    firstX = (int) me.getX();
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                if(me.getPointerCount() >= 2){
                    oldDist = getSpacing(me);
                    System.out.println(oldDist);
                }                       
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float newDist = getSpacing(me);
                    if(newDist - oldDist > 200 && oldDist != 0){
                       System.out.println("Enabled");
                    }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:         
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            }
            return true;

        }
 private float getSpacing(MotionEvent me){
            float difx = me.getX(0) - me.getX(1);
            float dify = me.getY(0) - me.getY(1);
            float spacing = (float) Math.sqrt(difx*difx + dify*dify);
            return spacing;
        }
 });
```

When I use it without the getPointerCount() condition in ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, I have an out of range error. But if I use the condition, the log doesn't show anything I print in the code. (Of course I use 2 fingers ! :) ), so the condition is never true, even if several fingers touch the screen at the same time.

How can I fix that ? Thank you.

My device is a GS3.

Comment: I don't think the ACTION_DOWN is delivered once for all fingers. It's unlikely that you get both your fingers down exactly at the same moment, within milliseconds of each other. I suggest you focus on ACTION_MOVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `me.getActionMasked()` instead of `me.getAction()`

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer, that works perfectly ! ;) But I tried to understand in other answers on the site what is the difference between getAction and getActionMasked, but still sceptic. Can you explain me ? Thank you again.

Comment: No problem :) getAction() will return the action that happened along with any information about the pointer involved. getActionMasked() masks out the pointer info and only returns the action that happened; it's similar to doing `getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK`. Also, getAction() will only give you ACTION_DOWN etc, but never the pointer counterpart like ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, which is why it worked the first time without the if-statement because of case-fall-through, but not the second time with it :)